# Know if user give number or string with scanner (java)

Tags: java

Hi I want to do something in java.
I have a scanner, if the user gives us a number I do something if it's a string I do something else.
It works with but not like I want, because when I give a int like 12 java knows that's it's a number but when I give something like 12.5 he thinks it's string.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(in.hasNextDouble()){
            System.out.println("number");
        }else if(in.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("text");
        }
```

thx

Comment: It is working fine on my system though. Could you try again?

Comment: same here..working fine on mine too.

Comment: no don't work on me, when you type 12.5 he thinks it's a string

Comment: That's because Java uses a , (comma) for decimal numbers. 12,5 should work.

Comment: @MystyxMac this sounds like it uses a comma generally, but I think you mean it might in this case, depending on the locale. The locale can be specified for the Scanner instance.

Comment: @D.Everhard Yes, that would be even better. Didn't think that far while writing the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to validate your input:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = in.nextLine();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+([.]([0-9]+))?");
if(p.matcher(line).matches()){
    System.out.println("number");
} else {
    System.out.println("text");
}
```

Comment: it works fine, know i realize the importance of regular expression.

Comment: This behaviour could be problematic depending on what you want to do. If you want the user to enter only a number, or only text, this will not work as expected. The regex will tell you if there is a number in the text, so if you typed `hello 2.0 world`, it would match. You then try to read a double from the input, and get a parse exception. Regex by default is greedy, and it's often more complicated to get the rightr output than anticipated.

Comment: The following regex will match only a number, so `hello 2.0 world` will not match, but `2.0` will. - `^[0-9]+([.]([0-9]+))?$`  - explained : the caret at the start marks the start of the string, the dollar sign marks the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Define a local for the scanner to tell it what decimal formatting to use

```
 // change the locale of the scanner
   in.useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

By default, it whichever locale is set as the default for your JVM, so if that is defined to use a comma separator, this will be expected on the scanner input.
Setting the `ENGLISH` locale will use a dot, as will any other locale which uses a dot separator in decimal numbers.

Comment: This is partly correct. By default it uses comma separator **if that is the separator of your JVMs locale**. You can change the locale for the JVM, or just for the Scanner. If your JVMs locale is english, your Scanner will also use the dot as the default.

Comment: @D.Everhard - Thats a good point. I'll ammend the answer for clarity